# How to make sure build is triggered only for pull request merge in CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to automate the build process using webhook provided by AWS code build. I am having a Bitbucket account. Currently, I see 3 options to configure webhook, 1. Push 2.Pull request created 3.Pull request updated. But I only want to trigger when my pull request is merged to develop branch.

Do I have to configure some filter using regular expression? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

CodeBuild now supports PR builds for merges in Bitbucket. Sample here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-bitbucket-pull-request.html#sample-bitbucket-pull-request-filter-webhook-events

Comment: When can we expect this feature to be out, or when can we expect codePipeline to support BitBucket as a source?